# Recommended to use 1 or 2 voltage regulators?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have currently designed the circuit given below. It is wireless power transfer circuit based on the ZVS principle. Originally I had the points numbered 1 and 2 connected to each other to the power supply. This would cause a problem, as when I increased the Vin, I was getting values closes to 10-12V, 2A+. This would cause the ESD diodes to burn through and heat the MOSFETS. To mitigate this issue I decided to cut the connection and supply the both with different voltages at points 1 and 2. This has seemed to solve the issue. I require about 7.5V,1A at point 1, and about 8-12V on point 2(This value is depending on which voltage regulator is available, it is responsible only for the MOSFETs switching.)

Since the circuit is being supplied by a 12V input, I wanted to know what a good voltage regulator selection would be, currently i have selected a switching voltage regulator [171021801](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/171021801.pdf) by würth elektronik.
For point 2 I am still looking for a suitable option. Is there a simpler and cheaper option to go about it. Point 2 requires about min 8V(anything between 8-12V), 0.2A.

[image: ZVS based wireless power transfer circuit]

Comment: Browse Digikey for LDOs. Configure the Search, that Output1 and Output2 have a Voltage range selected. This way, you can get a IC with dual LDOs in a single Package (Less board space, smaller BOM).

Comment: For everyone's sanity, *please* use standard symbols for standard parts! Transistors are not rectangular blocks, and inductors are not a series of full circles chained together! Using non-standard symbols makes your circuit harder to decipher, which in turn makes it unnecessarily difficult for anyone else to help you with it.

Comment: @brhans, yes i understand. The footprints for these components were downloaded using altium library loaded plugin in Altium(3rd party). They were like that when I downloaded them, and i didn't bother changing them for the sake of time. That being said, you are right for someone else other than myself trying to understand it, it is a difficult to decipher it.